# Use Facebook JavaScript API without Mobile Site URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, firefox-os

I'm developing a Firefox OS App and I want to use the feed dialog [1] of Facebook to let the user post a prefilled text message on his timeline.

I guess the only option I have to do so is to register a Mobile Web App on developer.facebook.com. But here I have to enter a Mobile Site URL which I don't have, as in my case the App is running from the local filesystem of the Firefox OS device. The URL is something like "app://...id.../index.html".

How can I integrated with Facebook?

Opening https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php is not an option as it is designed to share a URL only, but I need the user to post predefined text message.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: You are not supposed to pre-fill the message the user posts (i.e., Platform Policies _forbid_ you from doing so), and with the Feed dialog you actually can’t do so any more.

Answer (score 0):

For the feed dialog I think you would be fine entering any valid URL you like into the mobile app field - I'm pretty sure it doesn't verify the origin domain for posts to the feed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case:
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the URL to be reachable by Facebook, so you can use whatever you want (you can use localhost)

Just make sure to use the FB API from an URL you have registered there.